# choose 1 song to be played 3 times and the rest only once

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There're 10 songs in an MP3 player. Each time the player plays 5 random songs.What is the probability that one song will be played 3 times and the rest of the songs will not be played more than once?

I think that first we need to choose the song which will be played 3 times: $\binom{10}{1}$. The remaining two songs can be played in $P(9,2)$ ways. I can't think of though how to spread those songs out because there can be different positions and the same songs for example do not need to play sequentially.

Comment: The answer below already is correct, but in case it wasn't clear, your own work is just missing the step of picking which three of the five locations in the playlist are taken by the identical songs, increasing the count by $\binom{5}{3}=10$

Comment: $\dfrac{\binom{10}{3}\cdot\binom{3}{1}\cdot\frac{5!}{3!\cdot1!\cdot1!}}{10^5}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the denominator is $10^5$

After you choose the song to be played 3 times, there are $10$ different songs that could be.

$\binom{5}{3} = 10$ different ways it could be played.  And choosing the remaining songs can be done in $9\cdot 8$ ways. So its $\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 10\cdot 10}{10^5} = \frac{7200}{100000}=\frac{9}{125}$

Comment: You don't need to sign your name at the end of your posts since your account name is always shown at the bottom anyways.

Comment: that was an accident, sorry. i commented my answer instead of posting it and i just copy pasted over

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the number of ways to do it, as a product of the following:

- Number of ways to choose $3$ out of $10$ songs: $\binom{10}{3}$
- Number of ways to choose $1$ out of $3$ songs to play $3$ times: $\binom{3}{1}$
- Number of ways to arrange $3$ identical songs, $1$ distinct song and $1$ distinct song: $\frac{(3+1+1)!}{3!\times1!\times1!}$

---

Then, calculate the total number of ways to choose $1$ out of $10$ songs $5$ times: $\binom{10}{1}^5$

---

Finally, in order to compute the probability, divide the former by the latter:

$$\frac{\binom{10}{3}\times\binom{3}{1}\times\frac{(3+1+1)!}{3!\times1!\times1!}}{\binom{10}{1}^5}$$